How to warp a function $z = f(x,y)$ such that the $xy$-plane will located on the surface $z = x^2$?
The warp should preferably preserve distances.
I am not familiar with the branch of mathematics that deals with such problems, so I apologize for not providing an attempt at a solution.

Is the goal, in effect, to wrap a flat sheet of material around a parabolic cylinder (the graph $z = x^2$), i.e., to describe the wrapping as a parametric map?

@AndrewD.Hwang Yes, kind of. However, the sheet of material is not exactly flat, it has some bumps. Kind of like a road with some potholes.

This is not possible for extrinsic distance unless $f$ already creates shape of the sheet $(x, y, x^2)$ (i.e. rotated, reflected, translated), since isometry of subset of $\mathbb R^3$ can be extended to isometry of whole space. This is not possible as well for geodesic distance (the one I think you had in mind) if any "bumps" are present due to Gauss's Theorema Egregium - I presume any "bumps" would create some points of non-zero curvature, where on target space the curvature is zero. The latter applies to differentiable functions $f$, but intuitively it should be true for all $f$.

I see; is this a practical question about how to wrap physical material (perhaps non-slip floor covering) around a cylinder with parabolic cross section, or a mathematical question (in which case Esgeriath's comment is about as good an answer as can be hoped for)? <> Either way, could you please edit the question to clarify exactly what is the goal?

I am asking the question from a practical standpoint. I want to simulate surface defects such as erosion, pits and bumps on a curved object (the parabolic cylinder). For example, a 2D Gaussian function can represent a dent. But I would need to warp this function such that it follows the curvature of the parabolic cylinder.
